# do_shortcode not parsing a shortcode inside an acf field (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I need to parse a shortcode in an acf field.
I tried both Wysiwyg Editor & Text Area, but they show a shortcode text.
when I echo the shortcode, it loads the function well, but I need to parse it inside the field instead of echo it:

```
$myvalue = get_field( "field_60f5d9a277654" ); echo do_shortcode($myvalue);
```

Would you please let me know how to parse it?
I took the following action:

1. Wrote a shortcode [ajaxdomainchecker] into Wysiwyg Editor & Text Area (no format) field:
   [image]
2. Tried the following code in a functions.php:

```
add_filter('acf/format_value/key=field_60f5d9a277898', 'do_shortcode');
```

```
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=testsc', 'do_shortcode');
```

```
function my_acf_format_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    return do_shortcode( $value );
}
add_filter('acf/format_value/key=field_60f5d9a277898', 'my_acf_format_value', 10, 3);
```

Thank you.

Comment: For this you need to add filters where you call the field.

echo apply_filters('the_content', get_field('field_60f5d9a277654'));

Comment: What exactly isn’t working about the attempt to add a format_value filter? After all, this is exactly the way described in the documentation, https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-format_value/#example Are you sure the context in which this field value gets requested, _applies_ formatting?

Comment: @ZealousWeb:thanks for your comments. Yeah, echo works, but parsing doesn't work...

Comment: What does your shortcode do? If all it does it output simple text/markup just using get_field or the_field should work. But if you're trying to load additional resources to the header, such as .js or .css files, that could be the cause of the problem, there's several ACF support threads about that case including this one: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/theme-shortcodes-in-wysiwyg-field/

Comment: @CBroe:Thanks for your comments. Yeah, the code is same as I worte. Console shows no error, echo loads the function, but it just doesn't parse the shortcode in an acf field. So, it loads out of the acf field, not loads inside the acf field.